# Kubernetes request to all instances

Tags: c#, kubernetes, rabbitmq, replicaset

I have a k8s cluster with 3 API replicas and 2 TCP server replicas. They communicate using RabbitMQ.
The TCP servers have open TCP connections with clients somewhere identified by an ID.

Now, I wish to request if a certain client ID is connected to either of the TCP server replicas.

How would you accomplish that?

I can think of 2 (ugly) ways;

1. Have API X FanOut an identifiable message that is received by all replicas of the TCP server and then have them FanOut another message with the result to all replicas of the API. API X is awaiting the response messages until a non-null received or a timeout occurs.
2. Have all the TCP server instances save their connections to a Redis cache. Then API X can just check the Redis cache.

Comment: I'd go with 2, but here's how we do it for background jobs: multiple replicas running jobs (seconds to hours). We have start, progress, end integration events send via Rabbit to a dedicated service which a) updates the status in a mongodb and b) updates FE via SignalR - slightly different, guessing the number of jobs is way lower than the number of connections you have to handle...

Comment: I ended up using RabbitMQ to broadcast a "connection established" and "connection lost" event. The API subscribes to this event and saves the channel identifier in the SQL database.